# I have updated flutter and android studio. now any new dependencies are not installing

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am beginner in flutter and I have updated flutter and android studio. now any new dependencies are not installing.

When try to build it gives fallowing error.

> Note: C:\Users{user
> name}AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_tts-2.1.0\android\src\main\java\com\tundralabs\fluttertts\FlutterTtsPlugin.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':flutter_tts:extractDebugAnnotations'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_tts:lintClassPath'.
>   Could not download lint-checks-27.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:27.1.1)
>   > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/27.1.1/lint-checks-27.1.1.jar'.
>   > Tag mismatch!
>   Could not download kotlin-compiler-27.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:27.1.1)
>   > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/27.1.1/kotlin-compiler-27.1.1.jar'.
>   > Tag mismatch!
>   Could not download uast-27.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:27.1.1)
>   > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/27.1.1/uast-27.1.1.jar'.
>   > Tag mismatch!
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 17s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed
> with exit code 1